# Consuming messages no longer works after upgrading to Spring Integration 5

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm trying to upgrade a project using Spring Integration 4.3 and Spring Boot 1.6 to Spring Integration 5.1 and Spring Boot 2.1. Previously I had the following configuration:

```java
IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "queueName")
                    .id("myId")
                    .autoStartup(autoStartup)
                    .prefetchCount(10)
                    .concurrentConsumers(2)
                    .maxConcurrentConsumers(3)
                    .messageConverter(messageConverter()))
                    .aggregate(a -> a.correlationExpression("payload.entityId")
                                    .releaseExpression("size() eq iterator().next().payload.batchSize")
                                    .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                                    .groupTimeout(2000)
                                    .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                                    .outputProcessor(myMessageGroupProcessor))
                    .handle(serviceActivatorBean, "myMethod", e -> e.advice(requestHandlerRetryAdviceForIntegrationFlow()))
                    .get();
```

During the upgrade process I've tried to follow the documentation [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-4.3-to-5.0-Migration-Guide) and thus changed the configuration to this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableIntegration
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean(name = "myFlowId")
    public IntegrationFlow myFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ServiceActivatorBean serviceActivatorBean,
                                  @Value("${spring.integration.flow.auto-startup:true}") boolean autoStartup,
                                  MyMessageGroupProcessor myMessageGroupProcessor) {
        IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "queueName")
                        .id("myId")
                        .autoStartup(autoStartup)
                        .configureContainer(c -> c.acknowledgeMode(MANUAL)
                            .prefetchCount(10)
                            .concurrentConsumers(2)
                            .maxConcurrentConsumers(3)
                        )
                        .messageConverter(messageConverter()))
                        .aggregate(a -> a.correlationExpression("payload.entityId")
                                        .releaseExpression("size() eq one().payload.batchSize")
                                        .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                                        .groupTimeout(2000)
                                        .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                                        .outputProcessor(myMessageGroupProcessor))
                        .handle(serviceActivatorBean, "myMethod", e -> e.advice(requestHandlerRetryAdviceForIntegrationFlow()))
                        .get();
    }
}
```

But when I publish messages it doesn't seem like they're received/handled by the integration flow. I get no error logs (or any logs at all for that matter even though I enable debug logging) and I'm not quite sure where to start debugging. I'm positive that the messages are actually published to RabbitMQ so that's not the problem. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was actually not due to Spring Integration, rather it had to do with changes in Spring AMQP. Previously "declarables" could be created like this:

```java
@Bean
List<Binding> myBinding() {
    return List.of(<binding1>, <binding2>, ..)
}
```

but in Spring AMQP 2.1 this should be changed to:

```java
@Bean
Declarables myBinding() {
    return new Declarables(List.of(<binding1>, <binding2>, ..))
}
```

See documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/#_rabbitadmin_changes).

Btw, my `releaseExpression` was also wrong, it should be `size() eq one.payload.batchSize`.

Comment: You can use `releaseStrategy(ReleaseStrategy releaseStrategy)` as a lambda for more Java code context and readability.